# Spring boot on Kubernetes does not get restarted on java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, kubernetes, jvm, out-of-memory

I have been running a spring boot application on Kubernetes with using JDK 11 image. My expectation is that when the JVM hits out of memory exception then the pod should be killed so that Kubernetes can bring up a larger pod. I can confirm that this is not what's happening. I am not sure if there are some JVM arguments I have to set that I am missing or perhaps some Kubernetes configurations to be aware of this situation.

I am using the following JVM arguments:

```
-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=20.0 -XX:MinRAMPercentage=50.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+ExitOnOutofMemoryError
```

The thrown exceptions:

```
{
  "message": "Stopping container due to an Error",
  "logger_name": "org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer",
  "thread_name": "KafkaConsumerDestination{consumerDestinationName='message-submitted', partitions=21, dlqName='dlq'}.container-0-C-1",
  "level": "ERROR",
  "stack_trace": "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space\n\tat java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3745)\n\tat java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:120)\n\tat java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:95)\n\tat java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:156)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.utils.IoUtils.toByteArray(IoUtils.java:49)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.ResponseTransformer.lambda$toBytes$3(ResponseTransformer.java:175)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.ResponseTransformer$$Lambda$1517/0x0000000101087040.transform(Unknown Source)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler$HttpResponseHandlerAdapter.transformResponse(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:154)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler$HttpResponseHandlerAdapter.handle(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:142)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleSuccessResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:89)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:70)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:58)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:41)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:64)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:36)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:77)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:39)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.doExecute(RetryableStage.java:113)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.execute(RetryableStage.java:86)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:62)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:42)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:57)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:37)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)\n"
}


{
  "message": "Error while stopping the container: ",
  "logger_name": "org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer",
  "thread_name": "KafkaConsumerDestination{consumerDestinationName='message-submitted', partitions=21, dlqName='dlq'}.container-0-C-1",
  "level": "ERROR",
  "stack_trace": "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space\n\tat java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3745)\n\tat java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:120)\n\tat java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:95)\n\tat java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:156)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.utils.IoUtils.toByteArray(IoUtils.java:49)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.ResponseTransformer.lambda$toBytes$3(ResponseTransformer.java:175)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.ResponseTransformer$$Lambda$1517/0x0000000101087040.transform(Unknown Source)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler$HttpResponseHandlerAdapter.transformResponse(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:154)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler$HttpResponseHandlerAdapter.handle(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:142)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleSuccessResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:89)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:70)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:58)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:41)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:64)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:36)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:77)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:39)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.doExecute(RetryableStage.java:113)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.execute(RetryableStage.java:86)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:62)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:42)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:57)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:37)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)\n"
}
```

I think what's happening is OOM exception causes the pod to shutdown and then on trying to shutdown the pod the same exception is being thrown. So I tried to kill the pod regardless by adding `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p` but it didn't help.

On a slightly different note, the pod memory limit is 2Gi. However, the pod reaches to OOM exception on about 700Mi, so I don't think there is not enough memory, just the pod throws an exception before even trying to expand the memory:

```
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1"
        memory: 2Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 10m
        memory: 128Mi
```

I have also tested `-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError` and it didn't help to resolve my situation and pod keeps throwing OOM on the attempt to shutdown the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised there was a typo in my config. It must be `ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` not `ExitOnOutofMemoryError`. Here are the params I am using and they work smoothly:

```
-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=20.0 -XX:MinRAMPercentage=50.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Answer (score 1):

Minikube may not have enough memory.

You can check memory settings by
minikube start -h

Then
minikube stop && minikube start --cpus 4 --memory 2048

Update:
try setting heap size -Xms1g -Xmx2g while starting java application

Comment: I am running Kubernetes on AWS and there is plenty of memory available.

Comment: Try setting heap memory param while starting java app

Comment: Do you mean "Xmx" and "Xms"?

Comment: Although I don't want to use -Xms and -Xmx as I need to update it with the size of pod, it did not work. The problem is the pod memory does not grow. So even though I have set the limit to 2Gi, it initializes the pod with max 700 Mi which would cause OOM. I expected the pod memory size to grow but I cannot see that beyond a certain point. I am not sure if there is some sort of other limits that I am missing. Maybe some limits with the kubernetes auto-scalar ...

Comment: I suspect that My application got to OOM very quickly and did not get a chance to Kubelet to poll the metrics and grow the memory size. 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#kubelet-may-not-observe-memory-pressure-right-away

Comment: @Ali did you ever solve this issue? I have the same setup, facing the same issue.

Comment: @GeorgeCimpoies Yes. I just added the answer. It was just a typo!